# Spinner - selected item not getting in textview

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I am creating an app in which I have taken a spinner and a textview.
I want that the item selected should appear in textview.

I have made the app but the problem is it is not taking the value of the item selected in string and the app is forcefully shutting down.
What should I do?

Here is **MainActivity.class** :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

            TextView tv;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.access_level,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                //  spinner.setPrompt("Choose any one");

            spinner.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(adapter,
                    R.layout.row_spinner, this));
            adapter.getItem(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()); 

            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String str = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv1)).getText().toString();
                    System.out.println(item);
                    System.out.println(str);
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </Spinner>

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the adapter which I have taken for the spinner -

```
        NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter.class - 


            public class NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter,
            ListAdapter {

                protected static final int EXTRA = 1;
                protected SpinnerAdapter adapter;
                protected Context context;
                protected int nothingSelectedLayout;
                protected int nothingSelectedDropdownLayout;
                protected LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

                public NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter,
                        int nothingSelectedLayout, Context context) {

                    this(spinnerAdapter, nothingSelectedLayout, -1, context);
                }

                public NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter,
                    int nothingSelectedLayout, int nothingSelectedDropdownLayout,
                    Context context) {
                this.adapter = spinnerAdapter;
                this.context = context;
                this.nothingSelectedLayout = nothingSelectedLayout;
                this.nothingSelectedDropdownLayout = nothingSelectedDropdownLayout;
                layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                }

                @Override
                public final View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                    if (position == 0) {
                    return getNothingSelectedView(parent);
                    }
                    return adapter.getView(position - EXTRA, null, parent); // Could re-use

                }

                protected View getNothingSelectedView(ViewGroup parent) {
                return layoutInflater.inflate(nothingSelectedLayout, parent, false);
                }

                @Override
                public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                    if (position == 0) {
                        return nothingSelectedDropdownLayout == -1 ? new View(context)
                            : getNothingSelectedDropdownView(parent);
                    }

                // Could re-use the convertView if possible, use setTag...
                return adapter.getDropDownView(position - EXTRA, null, parent);
                }

                protected View getNothingSelectedDropdownView(ViewGroup parent) {
                return layoutInflater.inflate(nothingSelectedDropdownLayout, parent,
                        false);
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                int count = adapter.getCount();
                return count == 0 ? 0 : count + EXTRA;
                }

                @Override
                public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position == 0 ? null : adapter.getItem(position - EXTRA);
                }

                @Override
                public int getItemViewType(int position) {

                return position == 0 ? getViewTypeCount() - EXTRA : adapter
                        .getItemViewType(position - EXTRA);
                }

                @Override
                public int getViewTypeCount() {
                return adapter.getViewTypeCount() + EXTRA;
                }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int position) {
                return adapter.getItemId(position - EXTRA);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean hasStableIds() {
                return adapter.hasStableIds();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isEmpty() {
                return adapter.isEmpty();
                }

                @Override
                public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
                adapter.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
                }

                @Override
                public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
                adapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
                return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                return position == 0 ? false : true; // Don't allow the 'nothing
                                                        // selected'
                                                        // item to be picked.
                }

            }
```

Here is the xml for the spinner -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="Select Access Level"
android:textColor="#808080"
android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Comment: I think you should add `tv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tv1)` after `setContentView()`. If you want selected item to show in textview then you should `String str = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();` and set it to textview like `tv.setText(str)` inside the `onItemSelected` method. It will be better to answer if you post the logcat.

Comment: You are probably getting NPE. Can you post the stacktrace

Comment: When i am giving - String str = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); and printing str, it is getting force close.

Comment: @Raghunandan Here is the edited code -                           String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
System.out.println(item); and logcat details are - java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

> I want that the item selected should appear in textview.

Put following line just after `setContentView()`

```
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
```

And use following code:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                String itemText = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                tv.setText(itemText);
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: When i am using this - tv.setText(itemText); , the app is getting force close.

Comment: what exception you are getting?

Comment: 06-13 02:25:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1132): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 02:25:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1132): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 02:25:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1132):  at com.example.spinner1example.MainActivity$1.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:36)

Comment: which is your line number 36?

Comment: it is just because i am taking                                   String itemText = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); instead of                                                       Object itemText = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); and printing it in tv.setText(itemText);

Comment: line number 36 is -                                               String itemText = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

Comment: that means parent.getItemAtPosition(position) is giving you null. Plz check its value to confirm.

Comment: No..when i am taking Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position); and doing System.out.println(item), it is showing in the correct values in the logcat.

Comment: But object cannot be taken directly into textview, that's what the problem is arising

Answer (score 0):

Try This

MainActivity.class -

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        TextView tv;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,R.array.access_level);
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
               String item =(String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                tv.setText(item);
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: where is the edited code? I have checked your code..it is showing the same problem i.e. the item which I am getting can not be viewed on textview due to null pointer exception on -   tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

Comment: Why are you type casting the string while you can use this in the simple way like:Object text = sp.getSelectedItem();
     
     String str=text.toString();
     TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     
     tv.setText(str);
If String is facing problem then let me know

Comment: What is Object? I can print object but cannot set object on any text because after doing tv.setText(objectname); , the app is showing NPE on this line.

Comment: Ojeect is the super class of all class in java. For more read this http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html

Comment: I know @Aman Object is super class but after setting the objectname on textview it is giving null pointer exception.

Comment: We can use settext(String) not setext(Object) as you are trying to.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error here because you print  Object "item". Also **you are not getting the selected item from the spinner and still not set it to the text view**. Change your code to this :

```
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                tv.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: It is giving NPE on this line - tv.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());